# Aliasing two different versions of the same program in linux?

Tags: linux, shell, path, environment-variables, alias

I have an old version of a program sitting on my machine. This program recently had a version upgrade. The way I used to run my old program was by typing "runProgram". The path to the runscript of my program was specified in my PATH variable as

```
PATH = ....:/path/to/my/old/programs/bin
```

I want to run the new version of this same program alongside my old program and the way I was thinking of doing it was by modifying my PATH variable as follows:

```
PATH = ....:/path/to/my/old/programs/bin:/path/to/my/new/programs/bin
```

What I want to achieve is some way to alias these two paths so that when I type 'runVersion1', the previous version is executed and when I type 'runVersion2', the new version is executed?

Is there a way to achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want a shell alias? Or symbolic links? Or a new program that starts either one based on the name of the program? Is it fair game to simply rename the executables in each directory to include the version number? (See `/usr/bin/python2.6`, `/usr/bin/python2.7`,`/usr/bin/python3.2` available on Ubuntu...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the program itself runs other programs from the bin directory, then when you run a version 1 program, you want to ensure that the version 1 directory is on the PATH ahead of the version 2 directory, and vice versa when you run a version 2 program.  That is something I deal with all the time, and I deal with it by ensuring that the PATH is set appropriately.

In my $HOME/bin, I would place two scripts:

#### RunVersion1

```
 export PATH=/path/to/my/old/programs/bin:$PATH
 # Set other environment variables as needed
 exec runProgram "$@"
```

#### RunVersion2

```
 export PATH=/path/to/my/new/programs/bin:$PATH
 # Set other environment variables as needed
 exec runProgram "$@"
```

This technique of placing shell scripts on my PATH ahead of other programs allows me to pick which programs I run.

#### Semi-Generic Version

Often, I'll use a single program to set the environment and then link it to the various program names that I want to handle.  It then looks at `$0` and runs that:

```
 export PATH=/path/to/my/new/programs/bin:$PATH
 # Set other environment variables as needed
 exec $(basename $0 2) "$@"
```

If this script is linked to `RunProgram2`, the `basename` command lops off the 2 from the end of `RunProgram2` and then executes `RunProgram` from the more recent directory.

I've used this general technique for accessing 32-bit and 64-bit versions of the software on a single machine, too.  The programs I deal with tend to have more complex environments than just a setting of $PATH, so the scripts are bigger.

One of the main advantages of scripts in $HOME/bin over aliases and the like is that it doesn't much matter which shell I'm stuck with using; it works the same way.  Plus I don't have so many places to look to find where the alias is defined (because it isn't defined).

Answer (score 4):

I would put two alias definitions in your ~/.bashrc (depending what shell you are using).

```
alias runVersion1='/path/to/my/old/programs/bin/program'
alias runVersion2='/path/to/my/new/programs/bin/program'
```

After editing that file you need to relogin or simply execute

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you suggest with `$PATH` won't do what you want. One way that might:

Given that usually, `/usr/local/bin` is in `$PATH`, and that that is the standard location for "local binaries", you do the following:

```
sudo ln -s /path/to/my/old/programs/bin/myprogram /usr/local/bin/runVersion1
sudo ln -s /path/to/my/new/programs/bin/myprogram /usr/local/bin/runVersion2
```

Alternatively, if you don't want it to be system-wide (i.e. instead, just for your user), you could:

```
ln -s /path/to/my/old/programs/bin/myprogram $HOME/bin/runVersion1
ln -s /path/to/my/new/programs/bin/myprogram $HOME/bin/runVersion2
```

(assuming `$HOME/bin` is in your `$PATH`)

Now this won't *necessarily* fix your problem - could use a little more information in the question, BUT it should help you get further with what you're trying to do.

Comment: Is there a reason why you didn't make the links in $HOME/bin (where you don't need root privileges) rather than modifying a system directory?

Comment: No, retrospectively I answered with the unconscious assumption of wanting it system-wide, which was fairly unfounded... (I guess I should consider deleting this answer as better ones have been provided?)

Comment: Or just alter it to suggest 'or make the links in $HOME/bin or another convenient location on your PATH where you have write permission'.