# Multiple Version datadog Agent installation on EC2 ubuntu machine

Tags: amazon-ec2, datadog, datadog-dashboard, terraform-provider-datadog, open-telemetry-datadog

I have a EC2 instance which has DataDog Agent Version 5 running on it sending logs to XYZ datadog and is currently running. I want to install datadog Version 7 on the same machine without impacting the existing set up of Version 5. I need the new Version to send the logs to a new ABC datadog. How should i proceed on this?

Comment: Install the second version to a different path, then add aliases. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795688/aliasing-two-different-versions-of-the-same-program-in-linux